# Обращение к символам строки

Tags: java, строки

Как обращаться к символам строки в java?

Comment: Три ответа и все про charAt(), все три набрали репутацию забавно, четверый что ли добавить для халявы?

Comment: @AlekseiChibisov можешь попробовать ;)

Answer (score 8):

Метод `charAt()`

```
String str = "abc";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 7):

Для этого имеется метод `charAt` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Answer (score 5):

Вам тут поможет метод `charAt(index)` где `index` является номером буквы начиная с **0!!**

[Вот тут](http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/7.1.php)  также можете ознакомится со всеми основными операциями над строками.